# for_each_online_cpu get a pointer to cpuinfo_x86

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cpu

The *cpuinfo* module in linux kernel uses this code to get a pointer to the cpu:

```
ssize_t seq_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *ppos)
{
    // (...)
    struct seq_file *m = file->private_data;
    void *p;
    // (...)
    p = m->op->start(m, &pos);
```

And the *start* method is found in proc.c :

```
static void *c_start(struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
{
    *pos = cpumask_next(*pos - 1, cpu_online_mask);
    if ((*pos) < nr_cpu_ids)
        return &cpu_data(*pos);
    return NULL;
}
```

After the pointer to `void*` has been returned from it, it is next passed to *show* method:

```
err = m->op->show(m, p);
```

which assigns the pointer into pointer to *cpuinfo_x86*:

```
static int show_cpuinfo(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    struct cpuinfo_x86 *c = v;
    unsigned int cpu;
    int i;

    cpu = c->cpu_index;
```

However if I did in my code (linux kernel module) something similar:

```
    get_online_cpus();
    pos = kmalloc( sizeof( loff_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    *pos = 0;
    *pos = cpumask_next(*pos - 1, cpu_online_mask);
    if ( (*pos) < nr_cpu_ids)
    {
         c = &cpu_data(*pos);
         cpu = c->cpu_index;  // SIGSEGV !
    }
```

the pointer is incorrect (it points to something that might be valid address but I cannot access what it points to). The same thing happens if I use `for_each_online_cpu` macros:

```
for_each_online_cpu( cpuid)
{
    c = &cpu_data(cpuid);
```

Why do I get SIGSEGV? I know that file passed by **vfs** to *cpuinfo* is special, sequential file, but it doesn't seem to be related to `cpu_data` macro. As of now the only difference visible to me is that in the first case the pointer is passed to the function and then it is assigned inside that function, so we have a stack frame, etc. Is this related to optimizations?

If I do assignment in separate function it works:

```
static void*
mpsrv_get_cpu_ptr( loff_t *pos)
{
    *pos = cpumask_next(*pos - 1, cpu_possible_mask);

    if ( (*pos) < nr_cpu_ids)
        return &cpu_data(*pos);

    return NULL;
}

static void 
mpsrv_stat_cpu( struct mpsrv_cpu_info *cpu_info, void *v)
{
    struct cpuinfo_x86 *c = v;  // OK
    unsigned int cpu;

    cpu = c->cpu_index;         // OK
    // (...)
}

// code

    get_online_cpus();
    pos = cpu_n = 0;

    while ( ( p = mpsrv_get_cpu_ptr( &pos)))
    {
        mpsrv_stat_cpu( cpu_info, p);

        ++cpu_n;
        ++pos;
    }

    put_online_cpus();
```

The kernel code in *cpuinfo.c* also returns a pointer to *cpuinfo_x86* obtained in separate function, *c_start()*.
Please let me know if some additional information is needed. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you have multiple cores. Does this happen for all cores or is it possible that it works for first core and fails for others (that might be sleeping)?

Comment: @VAndrei Yes, it is on 4 cores Intel Xeon E5620, 2.4GHz. This code is running on a virtual machine. I debug remotely. If it is run not in function it fails on first core as well. I covered fetch of cpu mask with get_online_cpus() / put_online_cpus().

Comment: recently I have observed that kgdb module for debugging over ethernet, kgdboe.ko that is insmod-ed into kernel for debugging, disables all three cores so I stay always only with CPU0 while debugging